# What are the potential pitfalls of making the mint authority and freeze authority the same as the mint address?

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-program, mint

For the TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID spl-token program, it seems like it would be a best practice to make the mint authority and freeze authority different from the mint address, perhaps best to make them all different from each other. However, there is a small advantage to keeping the number of addresses we have to handle slim and easy to deal with.

What pitfalls or drawbacks can one expect to encounter down the road if the choice is made to make the mint and freeze authorities the same as the mint address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain, but I think you'll find that once initialised the mint address can't be used to pay fees because it's not owned by the system program (it'll be owned by the token program). That'd make it annoying to use it to send transactions because you'll need another signer as the fee payer. And at that point you might as well have made that other signer your authority instead so it can call the transactions on its own.